Nginx CORS configuration issues
Hello everyone I am in dire need of help. I am trying to program a Data Base on a raspberry pi so that a chat type web app I am developing can store its data. I use Mongo DB as a data base and nginx to configure my server.
For the moment I have a https URL connection up to my rasp which then reverse Proxy port 443 to port 50190 where is my Mango DB data base. The connection work but I am having a real hard time configuring the file in sites-available so that I don't have anymore CORS issues.
# Nginx configuration file for mongo reverse proxy
# The objectives are to redirect all connection via http and https to the URL or IP of the Raspberry Pi to the Mongo DB data base which is active on PORT 50190

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name.com;
    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain_name.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca_bundle.crt;

    #return 301 $scheme://domain_name.com;.fr.com$request_uri;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:50190;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Add CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;

        # Handle preflight CORS requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        # Clear headers from the upstream response that may interfere
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods';
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers';
    }


    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:50190/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Ajout des en-têtes CORS
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;

        # Gestion des requêtes CORS de pré-vérification (OPTIONS)
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        # Suppression des en-têtes de réponse en amont qui peuvent interférer
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods';
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers';
    }
...

I then specify the same for all different /api/.../. 
and then finish by 

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
}

I have had 301 issues which is why I wrote #return 301 $scheme:/domain_name.com;.com$request_uri;
And now I am having : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain_name.com;/api/messages/lastmsg' from origin 'https://domain_name_web_app.com;' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
As well as other CORS issues.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!
I tried to read Nginx documentation to understand about how to set up you localization but the best I came up with still can't fix it.

Pls i am still waiting for an answer. I can't manage to find a solution
